# Installing MySQL complete?

Tags: installation, mysql

How I can install mysql in ubuntu 12.04(gnome 3). So that I will have my mysql installation in `/usr/bin/mysql`

It's library and header files in `/usr/lib/mysql` and `/usr/include/mysql` respectively.

Last time I tried `sudo apt-get install mysql-server mysql-client mysql-common`
The mysql has been installed in `/usr/bin/mysql`. It's header files were in `/usr/include/mysql` but library files were not present. and libmysqlclient.so was in `/usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/` which should not be there. I need it to be in `/usr/lib/mysql`

Help me out in solving this problem :(

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You *could* use a `.tar.gz` download from [MySQL's homepage](http://dev.mysql.com/downloads/mysql/5.5.html) and extract the files to the proper folder, but for greater updateability, using the package manager (`apt-get`) is more recommended.

**Use symbolical links instead**

You can create symbolical links with the command `ln`, so that you will access the files from both directories.

**How to create the symbolical link?**

The command is used as follows: `ln -s target_file link_name`. Creating a symlink for *libmysqlclient.so* will look like this:

```
codeartist@computer:/usr/lib/mysql$ sudo ln -s /usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/libmysqlclient.so libmysqlclient.so
```

This way, opening the file `/usr/lib/mysql/libmysqlclient.so` will open the file at `/usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/libmysqlclient.so`. Be careful, because if you delete the target file (at *i386-...*, the symbolical link will be broken.

Comment: Thanks! But is there any way do the installation using apt-get

Comment: @codeartist Yes, you already mentioned you used `sudo apt-get install mysql-server mysql-client mysql-common` to do it. My solution of using the symbolical links are to be used after the package has been installed.

Comment: Okay then I will try it now! :)